# Change a HDFS file create date from UNIX

Tags: file, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I wish to use something like the touch command in UNIX to change a file's last modification date.
touch -d 20120101

The equivalent touchz command for hdfs does not support this.
hadoop fs -touchz -d 20120101

Is there any way to change the last modified date of a file in Hadoop using UNIX or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write the java code as @SCouto suggested, you can achieve with a simple workaround, below is my explanation of how you can achieve that.

```
#Changing the file timestamp to 201708210100 in local unix file system
[root@quickstart TestFolder]# touch -t 201708210100 SomeTestFile.txt 

[root@quickstart TestFolder]# ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 21 01:00 SomeTestFile.txt

#when copying the file to hdfs i'm using -p option which preserves the file timestamp
[root@quickstart TestFolder]# hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -p SomeTestFile.txt /Temp

#After copying the file if you look at the below TS its reflected the same way in as in local
[root@quickstart TestFolder]# hdfs dfs -ls /Temp/SomeTestFile.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          0 2017-08-21 01:00 /Temp/SomeTestFile.txt
```

P.S - Change the local file system time and when copying the file to hdfs use `-p` which will preserve and reflects the same time in HDFS as well.

If you are concerned about creating a new file and updating it every time you can do something like below with `-f` which overwrites/forces the file

```
#HDFS FILE SomeTestFile.txt
hdfs dfs -ls /Temp/SomeTestFile.txt

#To change the file TS for SomeTestFile.txt #Get it to local
hdfs dfs -get /Temp/SomeTestFile.txt /SomeFolderInLinux/

#Change the time in local with touch
touch -t 201701010100 /SomeFolderInLinux/SomeTestFile.txt

#Here is the main part of preserving the time and overwriting the file in hdfs
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -p -f /SomeFolderInLinux/SomeTestFile.txt /Temp/
```

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop does provide this facility

The general command line syntax is:
command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -touch [-a] [-m] [-t TIMESTAMP ] [-c]  ...

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using? Because in my version there's no touch command. There's a touchz command as mentioned above, but it doesn't fulfill the requirement.

Comment: works for me in hadoop 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no shell command to do that.

But can be done through the `Java` [API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#setTimes-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-long-long-)

> public void **setTimes**(Path p,
>                        long mtime,
>                        long atime)
>                 throws IOException
>
> Set access time of a file.
>
> Parameters:
>       p - The path
>       mtime - Set the modification time of this file. The number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. A value of -1 means that this call
>   should not set modification time.
>       atime - Set the access time of this file. The number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. A value of -1 means that this call
>   should not set access time.